# Подсчет ненулевых значение и вычисление среднего арифметического для данных из DataFrame pivot-table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Требуется python код для подсчета статистики на основе данных из DataFrame Pivot. Интересует best practice написания кода.

Для каждого столбца pivot  требуется вычислить кол-во ненулевых значений и среднее арифметическое ненулевых значений. Из полученных результатов выбрать TOP(4) значений с наибольшим количеством ненулевых значений и среднее арифметическим значением.

Исходный код (возвращает данные в pivot)

```
import pandas as pd 
import argparse as ap
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from prettytable import PrettyTable
from collections import Counter
import json
from random import randint
from itertools import chain
import operator
from functools import reduce

def ArgParser():
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your program')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--draws', help='Test result', required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return args

def main():

    args = ArgParser()
    draws = pd.read_csv(args['draws'], sep=';',header=0, index_col='draw_id')

    bc = (draws.stack().value_counts()).to_frame(name='count')
    bc['category'] = np.arange(len(bc)) // 3


    res = (draws.stack()
                .map(bc['category'])
                .reset_index(name='category')
                .pivot_table(index='draw_id', columns='category', 
                             aggfunc='size', fill_value=0))

    print(bc)

    print(res)


    print('The End')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Ожидаемый результат на примере первых 10 строк из pivot table

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Зеленым цветом отмечен TOP(4)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Промежуточные данные (часть) из Pivot

```
category  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11
draw_id                                                 
1          0   0   2   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   1
2          1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0
3          0   0   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   2   1   1
4          1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
5          0   2   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1
6          1   2   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0
7          0   0   1   1   2   0   0   0   2   0   0   1
8          0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0
9          1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1
10         1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0
11         0   0   2   0   0   1   1   0   0   2   0   1
12         1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   2
13         1   0   0   2   1   2   0   1   0   0   0   0
14         1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   2   0   1   0
15         0   2   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0
16         1   0   0   1   2   1   1   0   0   0   1   0
17         1   1   0   1   0   0   0   2   0   0   2   0
18         1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0
19         1   1   0   0   0   0   2   1   1   0   0   1
20         1   0   0   0   1   0   3   0   0   1   0   1
21         0   2   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0
22         0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1
23         1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   2   1   1   1
24         1   1   2   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   1   0
25         0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   2   1   0
26         2   2   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
27         0   0   1   2   1   0   2   0   0   0   1   0
28         1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
29         1   0   1   2   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0
30         1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
...       ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
74         2   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
75         1   1   0   0   2   0   1   1   0   1   0   0
76         2   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   2   1   0   0
77         1   1   2   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
78         1   2   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
79         2   2   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0
80         1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
81         0   0   1   1   2   0   1   1   0   0   0   1
82         2   1   0   0   2   0   1   0   0   0   0   1
83         0   1   0   0   1   2   0   0   2   1   0   0
84         0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0
85         2   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0
86         0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0
87         0   0   2   0   1   2   0   0   1   1   0   0
88         0   1   0   1   1   2   1   0   0   1   0   0
89         2   0   0   1   0   1   1   2   0   0   0   0
90         2   0   0   0   1   2   2   0   0   0   0   0
91         2   1   0   1   0   0   0   2   1   0   0   0
92         1   1   0   2   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   2
93         1   0   1   0   0   0   3   0   0   1   1   0
94         1   0   0   2   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0
95         0   1   0   1   2   1   0   0   0   1   0   1
96         1   1   2   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0
97         0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   2   1   1   1
98         2   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
99         0   0   0   0   2   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
100        0   3   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
101        0   0   2   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
102        0   0   2   0   0   0   2   1   0   0   1   1
103        0   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0

[103 rows x 12 columns]
```

Исходные данные

```
draw_id;ball1;ball2;ball3;ball4;ball5;ball6;ball7
1;9;11;17;29;30;33;36
2;5;6;9;11;15;33;28
3;4;5;10;14;20;30;8
4;4;21;22;25;26;36;6
5;1;11;13;17;24;29;36
6;2;17;22;24;27;30;1
7;4;15;26;28;29;35;34
8;12;22;24;26;31;33;2
9;6;9;16;24;33;34;17
10;3;8;12;19;27;31;1
11;4;5;7;9;14;20;25
12;9;20;32;33;35;36;22
13;16;19;23;25;29;32;12
14;6;10;11;17;33;35;15
15;1;5;16;19;22;28;33
16;3;6;7;8;16;29;12
17;1;3;10;19;24;32;23
18;9;25;27;29;33;35;22
19;7;13;17;18;21;34;6
20;7;14;18;20;27;33;28
21;1;3;5;8;22;23;25
22;4;5;13;19;28;34;11
23;3;24;26;32;35;36;14
24;2;7;18;22;30;32;4
25;5;22;28;30;31;33;3
26;1;4;6;28;31;32;13
27;7;10;15;18;23;30;8
28;6;10;12;16;18;19;4
29;9;12;16;21;23;27;3
30;6;15;18;19;25;29;2
31;4;7;22;28;29;30;15
32;3;7;14;18;33;35;29
33;4;14;21;23;28;29;30
34;2;5;9;21;26;27;20
35;1;3;9;11;13;17;27
36;11;13;15;28;32;35;18
37;3;11;16;21;28;35;15
38;1;2;12;13;14;15;6
39;5;10;13;16;18;21;20
40;1;4;18;23;32;36;7
41;6;9;13;17;18;35;23
42;11;13;19;23;24;27;12
43;2;3;8;14;32;35;25
44;1;5;12;14;21;25;9
45;2;4;15;25;28;31;9
46;19;21;23;26;30;35;2
47;11;16;22;23;24;30;8
48;8;9;11;27;30;35;32
49;1;15;22;26;31;32;25
50;3;5;8;12;16;21;7
51;7;8;13;21;22;32;30
52;1;4;8;14;27;30;12
53;2;16;20;22;27;30;21
54;1;5;16;25;27;36;22
55;4;26;28;30;32;33;6
56;5;10;13;18;24;27;29
57;1;4;5;8;22;25;28
58;3;11;24;27;29;34;17
59;1;2;6;9;14;23;32
60;5;10;12;15;24;33;22
61;5;12;15;23;24;32;18
62;2;5;11;13;25;28;10
63;8;13;18;19;27;31;12
64;7;9;11;23;32;34;22
65;2;4;7;15;27;30;26
66;4;12;15;16;17;19;11
67;6;7;9;12;17;19;27
68;12;17;25;27;32;33;36
69;6;19;20;26;27;35;21
70;6;15;21;32;34;35;1
71;4;7;9;10;14;23;26
72;6;21;26;30;31;32;28
73;3;8;13;22;29;31;12
74;6;8;13;15;27;34;5
75;8;13;24;29;31;33;6
76;6;14;17;23;26;32;21
77;4;9;15;16;23;32;13
78;1;8;13;23;27;33;24
79;1;13;16;26;29;32;6
80;9;12;16;22;24;35;32
81;8;9;18;19;23;28;20
82;1;6;7;20;28;29;32
83;8;17;22;25;26;31;11
84;3;11;18;24;26;29;1
85;10;11;13;21;27;30;6
86;2;13;23;25;30;35;29
87;14;16;17;25;29;30;4
88;7;8;12;22;25;31;16
89;16;23;24;27;32;33;19
90;6;16;18;25;27;28;7
91;13;15;17;19;24;32;6
92;1;12;15;19;27;34;36
93;3;6;7;9;18;33;31
94;6;11;12;14;21;29;23
95;8;11;14;15;29;36;22
96;1;9;14;25;30;32;26
97;4;10;25;31;35;36;17
98;9;16;27;32;35;36;23
99;10;21;28;29;31;34;17
100;1;12;13;24;26;33;22
101;2;4;15;18;19;30;8
102;4;7;10;19;30;33;34
103;1;11;15;18;28;31;26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создание "pivot-table" из `draws` DF:

```
bc = (draws.stack().value_counts()).to_frame(name='count')
bc['category'] = np.arange(len(bc)) // 3


pvt = (draws.stack()
            .map(bc['category'])
            .reset_index(name='category')
            .pivot_table(index='draw_id', columns='category', aggfunc='size'))
```

статистика по "pivot-table":

```
st = pvt.mean().to_frame(name='mean')
st['nonzero'] = (pvt > 0).sum()
res = st.nlargest(4, ['nonzero'])
```

результат:

```
In [30]: res
Out[30]:
              mean  nonzero
category
0         1.285714       63
1         1.280702       57
3         1.210526       57
4         1.203704       54
```

Comment: значение mean должно быть больше или равно единице. При вычислении среднего арифметического мы берем не нулевые записи (только игры в которых заданная категория присутствовала). По определению, наименьшее число category = 1, а среднее не может быть меньше 1.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, уберите параметр `fill_value=0`